# Subset table by replacing some row values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table only with 0 and 1. The first column has always only 1. 
The rows are padded with zero once the first 1 occurred.

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c( "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), Q1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1), Q3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Q4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Q5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I need to subset the table so that I search for each row for the last 1. If founded  keep it and replace the previous 1s with 0.

This is the expected output:

```
dt2 <- data.table(ID = c( "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), Q1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Q2=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q3=c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Q4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), Q5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Any clue how to solve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use a matrix?

```
wr = which(rowSums(dt[, -1]) > 0)
wc = max.col(dt[wr, -1], ties = "last")

m = matrix(0L, nrow(dt), nc, dimnames = list(dt[[1]], names(dt)[-1]))
m[cbind(wr, wc)] = 1L

    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
ID1  0  1  0  0  0
ID2  0  0  1  0  0
ID3  1  0  0  0  0
ID4  0  0  0  1  0
ID5  0  0  0  1  0
```

This can still be coerced back to data.table like `data.table(m, keep.rownames = "ID")`.

Alternately, keep your data in a more compact form?

```
DT = copy(dt)
DT[wr, Qmax := names(dt)[-1][max.col(dt[wr, -1], ties = "last")]]
DT[, paste0("Q", 1:5) := NULL]

    ID Qmax
1: ID1   Q2
2: ID2   Q3
3: ID3   Q1
4: ID4   Q4
5: ID5   Q4
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution using the tidyverse, not sure if this is the shortest or the fastest one possible.

First count the number of ones by row using rowSums, and add "Q" before to get the right name, the Q column will give you the column where to put the one. The `factor` is here to make sure that all Q1 to Q5 will appear in the result (if you don't factor then Q5 won't appear). Then spread to convert to wide format. The `ones` column is just here to be in the `value` argument of `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
dt2<-  dt %>% 
   mutate(ones=1, 
          Q = factor(paste0("Q",rowSums(dt[,paste0("Q",1:5)])),levels=paste0("Q",1:5))) %>% 
   select(ID,Q,ones) %>% 
   spread(Q,ones,fill=0,drop=FALSE) 

#   ID Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
#1 ID1  0  1  0  0  0
#2 ID2  0  0  1  0  0
#3 ID3  1  0  0  0  0
#4 ID4  0  0  0  1  0
#5 ID5  0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

another option but will not be faster than Frank's matrix approach

```
dt2 <- copy(dt)[, paste0("Q", 1:5) := 0L]
dt[, set(dt2, .I, .BY$col + 1L, 1L), .(col=max.col(dt[, -1L], ties="last"))]
```